# <apex:param/> tag seems to always assign the last value on visualforce page, regardless of which event was clicked

Tags: visualforce, actionfunction, actionsupport, apex-param

I have a VF page with 3 tabs. I can't figure out why the value assigned to the activeTab String always gets set to the last  value in the `<ul>`. I thought the events were separate for each `<apex:actionSupport/>` tag... could someone kindly tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Example: when the page first loads, the controller correctly sets the value to 'regularUSR'. However when any `<li>` is clicked, only the last value ('multiLicenseDeactivate') will get assigned.

UPDATE: I noticed that the onclick event apparently is firing for any click on the visualforce page, not just on the anchor tags / list items on the page.

VF page:

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">  
    <li id="li1" class="active"> 
      <a id="anchor1" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!tabWasChanged}" reRender="ResultPanel1,ResultPanel2">
          <apex:param value="regularUSR" assignTo="{!activeTab}"></apex:param>
        </apex:actionSupport>
      Standard USR</a>
    </li>

    <li id="li2">
      <a id="anchor2" href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!tabWasChanged}" reRender="ResultPanel1,ResultPanel2">
          <apex:param value="multiLicenseActivate" assignTo="{!activeTab}"></apex:param>
        </apex:actionSupport>
      License Request</a>
    </li>
    <li id="li3">
      <a id="anchor3" href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!tabWasChanged}" reRender="ResultPanel1,ResultPanel2">
          <apex:param value="multiLicenseDeactivate" assignTo="{!activeTab}"></apex:param>
        </apex:actionSupport>
      License Deactivation</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Extension:

```
public Boolean regularUSR {get;set;}
public Boolean multiLicenseActivate {get;set;}
public Boolean multiLicenseDeactivate {get;set;}
public String activeTab {get;set;}

public USRlicenseExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    u = (User_Support__c)stdController.getRecord();
    if(activeTab == null){activeTab = 'regularUSR';}
    tabWasChanged();
}

public PageReference tabWasChanged(){

    System.Debug('activeTab= '+activeTab);

    if(activeTab == 'regularUSR'){
        regularUSR = true;
        multiLicenseActivate = false;
        multiLicenseDeactivate = false;
    }

    else if(activeTab == 'multiLicenseActivate'){
        regularUSR = false;
        multiLicenseActivate = true;
        multiLicenseDeactivate = false;
    }

    else if(activeTab == 'multiLicenseDeactivate'){
        regularUSR = false;
        multiLicenseActivate = false;
        multiLicenseDeactivate = true;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: The docs state "adds AJAX support to another component" so maybe that why it is attaching to the page and not the element. Try wrapping the children of the `li` in an `output panel`  Also, Shots in the dark - The <li> has no Id so the Actionsupport is attached to `li` of which you have many. Try adding Id's to the `li`.  Second, if you want the action support to only happen on the `<a>` tag you need to put it inside of the <a> tag. Additionally, not sure of the behavior of Action support when it is NOT used as a child of another apex component.

Comment: I have updated my actionSupport and apex:param tags to be inside of the anchor tag... however it is still firing on any click on the page. I have also added ids to the list items and anchors, but is there a way to map the actionSupport or apex:params to those ids? I think I'm missing something...

Comment: do the `outputPanel` thing. I believe it needs to be a child of a component and not a regular html tag

Comment: That worked. You @Eric... are a life saver!

Comment: Glad I could help. Your comment on firing when the page was clicked was the key. Nicely asked question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm) state "adds AJAX support to another component"

```
<li id="li1" class="active"> 
  <apex:outPutPanel layout="inline">
  <a id="anchor1" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!tabWasChanged}" reRender="ResultPanel1,ResultPanel2">
      <apex:param value="regularUSR" assignTo="{!activeTab}"></apex:param>
    </apex:actionSupport>
  Standard USR</a>
   </apex:outPutPanel>
</li>
```